# How to fix 'ImportError: /home/... .../lib/libtorch.so.1: undefined symbol: nvrtcGetProgramLogSize' in DGL?

Tags: pytorch

I get an error in the importation of pytorch inside dgl (Deep Graph Library by DeepMind), concretely:

ImportError: /home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so.1: undefined symbol: nvrtcGetProgramLogSize

I tried to reinstall pytorch (uninstall reinstall with `conda un/install`). I also search in google and I found this https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/14973. There, they solve it linking in `libnvrtc.so` and `libcuda.so`, but I have no idea what that means. Does anyone know it?

This is the basic code:

```
import dgl
from parseador import train_df

g = dgl.DGLGraph()
g.add_nodes(5)
g.add_edges([0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3, 4])
g.ndata['h'] = th.randn(5, 3)
g.edata['h'] = th.randn(4, 4)
```

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Documentos/Repo/grafos.py", line 1, in <module>
    import dgl
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dgl/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import function
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dgl/function/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .message import *
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dgl/function/message.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .. import backend as F
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dgl/backend/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    load_backend(os.environ.get('DGLBACKEND', 'pytorch').lower())
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dgl/backend/__init__.py", line 18, in load_backend
    mod = importlib.import_module('.%s' % mod_name, __name__)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dgl/backend/pytorch/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .tensor import *
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dgl/backend/pytorch/tensor.py", line 5, in <module>
    import torch as th
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 102, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: /home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so.1: undefined symbol: nvrtcGetProgramLogSize
```

How can I fix this error? some time ago I run correctly this code in Windows 10, now I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: are you trying to run this on a GPU?

Comment: Nope, I'm trying in the CPU.

Answer (score 8):

I also ran into this, but I actually wanted to use GPU, so installing `pytorch-cpu` was not an option for me.

Instead, installing `pytorch` package from `pytorch` channel (instead of `defaults`) solved the issue for me: `conda install pytorch --channel pytorch`

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this same exception with `conda install pytorch-cpu`

Answer (score 0):

You should run your code on a GPU machine and make sure your pytorch is a GPU